# Audio(wav) to speech conversion - no desired output

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Input audio should be: "Katrina skipping school today. No special reason. It's just that between listening to the most boring teacher drone on or hanging out at a friend's house and maybe getting a little high were scored as." 
But I am getting: " no special reason School" 
**Audio file: https://recontent-1bca.kxcdn.com/v7.2/teens/assets/audio/attends1.mp3**
It is giving vague output using library **speech_recognition**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.WavFile("attends.wav") as source:             
    audio = r.record(source)                        

try:
    print("Transcription: " + r.recognize(audio))  
except LookupError:                                 
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

Comment: You have to be more specific, what is your code, how do you use the library, the options...

Comment: We need to see how you arrived at these results. You wouldn't show us a calculator and say "why is my answer 5?" without showing us the calculation you entered.

Comment: Input audio is needed

Comment: I have provided the mp3 link above